# Exchange 2013 & AD (on-premise) to Office365 Migration path recommendation

Tags: active-directory, migration, office365, exchange-server

I have the following setup:
    Exchange 2013 on-premise with 10 users
    AD on-premise

We have Office 365 premium licenses for each person in the company and have an Azure account etc.

I have been tasked with migrating the users to Office365 and also migrating AD

The Exchange Online licenses are not yet active, so currently, there are no user mailboxes on Office365.

We want Azure AD to replace our on-premise AD as at some point, the AD and Exchange servers (on-premise) will be decommissioned.

What path would be the best for me to take to do the migration?

I have read various pages on learn.microsoft.com about AD sync and AD Connect but am not sure whether or not this is the right way to go.  the docs all seem to be geared towards companies needing a hybrid setup and we don't want that, ultimately.

Tips and advice will be gratefully welcomed.

Best regards,

Neil.

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. You could try at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions, but I think you would be better off getting help directly from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the info @GabrielLuci